# Order date within a particular date limit in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a cart abandonment project where I am handling the data fetch through a procedure. In the process, I want to send reminder about cart to people who have placed order exactly two days before today. That is, if today is 24th, I want to send reminder to people who have added items to cart on 22nd.

```
So orderdate = 5/22/2017, 
@lagdays = getdate()-3 = 5/21/2017, 
@seldate = getdate() = 5/24/2017.
```

When I run the query, I need all the orders placed on 22nd alone. Below is my query.

```
select * from ordertable o where ((o.orderdate > @LagDays ) and (o.orderdate <  @seldate ))
```

However this query is fetching all the orders with orderdate 22,23,24. How to solve this?

Comment: What about `select * from ordertable o where ((o.orderdate > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 2, GETDATE()), 0) ) and (o.orderdate <  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) ))
` ?

Comment: Wow thanks! this worked. Can you post this as answer below instead of comment?

Comment: @Akansha, Nice to help you, the comment is posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the next code:-

```
select * from ordertable o 
where ((o.orderdate > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 2, GETDATE()), 0) ) 
and (o.orderdate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) ))
```

The approach is depends on getting the date only without time.

so if the today is 24th, the where criteria will be within

```
2017-05-22 00:00:00.000
```

&

```
2017-05-23 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from ordertable o where ((o.orderdate > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 2, GETDATE()), 0) ) and (o.orderdate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) ))

Thanks @ahmed abdelqader for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the table uses a DATETIME type.
While that SQL tries to compare it to variables that are DATES.

So you could cast that field to a date first before comparing it against dates.
By casting it, you basically remove the time part from it.

```
select *
from ordertable o
where cast(o.orderdate as date) > @lagdays and cast(o.orderdate as date) < @seldate;
```

Here's an example that only uses variables to demonstrate:

```
declare @lagdays DATE = GetDate()-3;
declare @seldate DATE = GetDate();

declare @ordertable table (id int identity(1,1), orderdate datetime);

insert into @ordertable (orderdate) values 
(GetDate()-4),
(GetDate()-3),
(GetDate()-2),
(GetDate());

select orderdate, cast(orderdate as date) as orderdate_as_date, @lagdays as lagdays, @seldate as seldate
from @ordertable 
where cast(orderdate as date) > @lagdays and cast(orderdate as date) < @seldate;
```